# How to programmatically connect an audio endpoint?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I want to control programmatically such functions as "Connect", "Disconnect", "Disable".

I found [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista) that allow switch between audio endpoints change volume and etc, but i can't found any way to "Connect" endpoint. I would like to know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Api research time! Its a different name.

Comment: @DeltaEnfieldWaid what did you mean?

Comment: Sorry i'm not quite accurate with endpoints, perhaps it's activate rather than connect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/audio-endpoint-builder-algorithm perhaps it needs to be re-initialized to detect all the new devices.